# In C#, how do I save a webpage to file without destroying whatever the encoding is?

Tags: c#, encoding

Here's what I got so far (that doesn't work). At this point I thought my target was Ansi encoded, but I really don't want to have to know at this point. My browser seems to be able to determine what encoding to use, How can I?

```
static void GetUrl(Uri uri, string localFileName)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    HttpWebResponse response;

    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    // Save the stream to file
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default);
    Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(localFileName);
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStream, Encoding.Default))
    {
        sw.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
     }
}
```

---

**After answers** (currently only tested on a UTF-8 site):

```
static void GetUrl(Uri uri, string localFileName)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    try
    {
        // Hope GetEncoding() knows how to parse the CharacterSet
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding);
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(localFileName, false, encoding))
        {
            sw.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        response.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your edit mean you are doing it like I suggested? If so, you should move the "Acceped Answer" tick.

Comment: Actually, I thought about it, but I don't know the protocol here. As Lubos did suggest checking the charset in the content-type portion of the header. Lubos has additional info, but you're suggestion of converting utf-8 is pretty valuable too. I wish I could merge the answers.

Comment: Lubos' answer led me to Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet) before I even read your post; but your post had actually C# code. I upvoted both, left him with the answer for being the first to lead me to the answer, and I posted the revised code to show respect for your post and future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways how web-browsers try to detect character encoding.

Look for (if it's HTML):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
```

or (for XHTML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

or sometimes it's even specified in http header

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Comment: I'm using the header information for the immediate situation.

Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);

This seems to do the trick for now.

Answer (score 2):

You should be looking for the encoding the server sends the response in. `Encoding.Default` does not cut the mustard here. :-)

```
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, enc);
Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(localFileName);
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStream, enc))
{  /* ... */ }
```

To be sure, you could convert everything to UTF-8 and store your file as UTF-8 always. That way you are never left with the need to guess the encoding when reading the file.